# How to interpret Unicode notation in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, unicode

How to convert formal Unicode notation like `'U+1F600'` into something like this: `'\U0001F600'`, which I saw represented as 'Python Src' at websites online?

My end-goal is to use Unicode for emojis in Python(2.x) and I am able to achieve it in this way:

```
unicode_string = '\U0001F600'
unicode_string.decode('unicode-escape')
```

I would appreciate if you could mention the different character sets involved in the above problem.

Comment: Are you just trying to convert a single character, or a string that might have these embedded in it?

Comment: I have a string like: "Have a nice day! U+1F600". If it's possible to directly parse a string like this, then it shortens the task. Otherwise, I could break the task into Unicode parsing and then string concatenation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is to just treat the notation as a string:

```
>>> s = 'U+1F600'
>>> s[2:] # chop off the U+
'1F600'
>>> s[2:].rjust(8, '0') # pad it to 8 characters with 0s
'0001F600'
>>> r'\U' + s[2:].rjust(8, '0') # prepend the `\U`
'\\U0001F600'
```

It might be a bit cleaner to parse the string as hex and then format the resulting number back out:

```
>>> int(s[2:], 16)
128512
>>> n = int(s[2:], 16)
>>> rf'\U{n:08X}'
'\\U0001F600'
```

… but I'm not sure it's really any easier to understand that way.

---

If you need to extract these from a larger string, you probably want a regular expression.

We want to match a literal `U+` followed by 1 to 8 hex digits, right? So, that's [`U\+[0-9a-fA-F]{1,8}`](https://regex101.com/r/Clo7vB/1). Except we really don't need to include the `U+` just to pull it off with `[2:]`, so let's group the rest of it: [`U\+([0-9a-fA-F]{1,8})`](https://regex101.com/r/Clo7vB/2).

```
>>> s = 'Hello U+1F600 world'
>>> re.search(r'U\+([0-9a-fA-F]{1,8})', s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(6, 13), match='U+1F600'>
>>> re.search(r'U\+([0-9a-fA-F]{1,8})', s).group(1)
'1F600'
```

Now, we can use `re.sub` with a function to apply the `\U` prepending and `rjust` padding:

```
>>> re.sub(r'U\+([0-9a-fA-F]{1,8})', lambda match: r'\U' + match.group(1).rjust(8, '0'), s)
'Hello \\U0001F600 world'
```

That's probably more readable if you define the function out-of-line:

```
>>> def padunimatch(match):
...     return r'\U' + match.group(1).rjust(8, '0')
>>> re.sub(r'U\+([0-9a-fA-F]{1,8})', padunimatch, s)
'Hello \\U0001F600 world'
```

Or, if you prefer to do it numerically:

```
>>> def padunimatch(match):
...     n = int(match.group(1), 16)
...     return rf'\U{n:08X}'
>>> re.sub(r'U\+([0-9a-fA-F]{1,8})', padunimatch, s)
'Hello \\U0001F600 world'
```

---

And of course you already know how to do the last part, because it's in your question, right? Well, not quite: you can't call `decode` on a string, only on a `bytes`. The simplest way around this is to use the codec directly:

```
>>> x = 'Hello \\U0001F600 world'
>>> codecs.decode(x, 'unicode_escape')
'Hello  world'
```

… unless you're using Python 2. In that case, the `str` type isn't a Unicode string, it's a byte-string, so `decode` actually works fine. But in Python 2, you'll run into other problems, unless all of your text is pure ASCII (with any non-ASCII characters encoded as `U+xxxx` sequences).

For example, let's say your input was:

```
>>> s = 'Hej U+1F600 världen'
```

In Python 3, that's fine. That `s` is a Unicode string. Under the covers, my console is sending Python UTF-8-encoded bytes to standard input and expecting to get UTF-8-encoded bytes back from standard output, but that just works like magic. (Well, not quite magic—you can `print(sys.stdin.encoding, sys.stdout.encoding)` to see that Python knows my console is UTF-8 and uses that to decode and encode on my behalf.)

In Python 2, it's not. If my console is UTF-8, what I've actually done is equivalent to:

```
>>> s = 'Hej U+1F600 v\xc3\xa4rlden'
```

… and if I try to decode that as `unicode-escape`, Python 2 will treat those `\xc3` and `\xa4` bytes as Latin-1 bytes, rather than UTF-8:

```
>>> s = 'Hej \U0001F600 v\xc3\xa4rlden'
```

… so what you end up with is:

```
>>> s.decode('unicode_escape')
u'Hej \U0001f600 v\xc3\xa4rlden'
>>> print(s.decode('unicode_escape'))
Hej  vÃ¤rlden
```

But what if you try to decode it as UTF-8 first, and then decode *that* as unicode_escape?

```
>>> s.decode('utf-8')
u'Hej \\U0001F600 v\xe4rlden'
>>> print(s.decode('utf-8'))
Hej \U0001F600 världen
>>> s.decode('utf-8').decode('unicode-escape')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Unlike Python 3, which just won't let you call `decode` on a Unicode string, Python 2 lets you do it—but it handles it by trying to `encode` to ASCII first, so it has something to `decode`, and that obviously fails here.

And you can't just use the codec directly, the way you can in Python 3:

```
>>> codecs.decode(s.decode('utf-8'), 'unicode_escape')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)
```

You could decode the UTF-8, then unicode-escape the result, then un-unicode-escape everything, but even that isn't quite right:

```
>>> print(s.decode('utf-8').encode('unicode_escape').decode('unicode_escape'))
Hej \U0001F600 världen
```

Why? Because `unicode-escape`, while fixing our existing Unicode character, also escaped our backslash!

If you know you definitely have no `\U` escapes in the original source that you didn't want parsed, there's a quick fix for this: just `replace` the escaped backslash:

```
>>> print(s.decode('utf-8').encode('unicode_escape').replace(r'\\U', r'\U').decode('unicode_escape'))
Hej  världen
```

If this all seems like a huge pain… well, yeah, that's why Python 3 exists, because dealing with Unicode properly in Python 2 (and notice that I didn't even *really* deal with it properly…) is a huge pain.

Comment: That is a super answer. With crystal explanations. Thank you. Could you also touch on the character-sets used here? Also, calling decode on a string is working apparently, is it treating it as bytes then?

Comment: @smaug Are you using Python 2? If so, that's why `decode` works on strings. I'll update the answer to cover that, but it would help to edit the question to say whether you care about 2.x or 3.x.